# How does the electromagnetic field behave in a complex circuit when first energized? Such as in a computer CPU booting up

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-fields, complex-systems

From what I understand in the case of a simple circuit, the electrons in the circuit wiring are steadily excited, i.e. energized, in a fairly complex way by the external energy input, as the energy flow increases to the operating parameters.

In the simplest lightbulb and battery circuit, this seems to be satisfactorily explained in the following: [Path of EM wave propagation in a circuit wire](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221053/path-of-em-wave-propagation-in-a-circuit-wire)

But how does this transition occur in a complex circuit?

Does it propagate like a fractal wave along the many branching and interconnecting paths of the circuit? How do the electrons know which way to move on a junction between multiple branches?

Answer (score 0):

Electrons "know" how to move at junctions by Kirchhoff's laws and by the laws of circuit element behavior. For complex circuits studied at turn-on, *transient analysis* is used, and the results are well-explained by these "ordinary" laws.

Comment: How do 'Kirchhoff's laws and by the laws of circuit element behavior' explain the motion of electrons at the junction between multiple circuit branches on an integrated circuit? Can you provide an example?

Comment: have you studied circuit analysis?

Comment: Yes quite extensively. And I've never seen a detailed example, along the lines in the linked post, for anything more complicated than the equivalent of a few lightbulbs and batteries.